# Emit a (loading) value from a Flow if it has not emitted any values after some time

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a repository that returns `Flow<Status<T>>`. `Status` can be `Status.Loading` or `Status.Data`. I would like the `Flow` to emit `Status.Loading` in case the repository has not yet returned any values for X milliseconds.

In pseudo code it would look something like this:

```
repository.fetchData()
  .emitDataOrLoading()
  .collect {
     when (it) {
       is Status.Loading -> // show loading indicator in case no data after X milliseconds
       is Status.Data -> // We have received the data.
     } 
  }
```

So I am looking for how to implement `.emitDataOrLoading()`

Comment: What is `fetchData()`? A Flow that emits values every time a repository value changes? Or just a suspend function that does a one-time fetch? If it's a Flow that continually monitors the database, do you only want to show the Loading state if it's the **first** value that takes a long time?

Comment: I guess, you can use debounce operator while emitting at repository.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Good question! In this case, it would mostly be a one-time fetch from a HTTP REST endpoint. So basically, it would for example return a page's data and we want to show the loading indicator while waiting for the page to load.

Comment: @VivekGupta Can you elaborate?

Comment: The problem with debouncing is that when the fetched value does arrive, it will be delayed downstream by the debounce interval.

Comment: here -> https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html

Comment: @VivekGupta I do not want to delay the response which I understand debounce() will do. Instead, what I am looking for is "emit the data as soon as possible, but if data has not arrived within X ms, then emit loading".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be created using the `channelFlow` builder. Maybe there is a simpler way with operators but I couldn't come up with one.

If `fetchData()` is a one-time fetching suspend function, you could do:

```
fun <R, T: R, L: R> lazyFlowOfWithLoadStateIfDelayed(cutoffDelay: Long, loadState: L, fetchAction: suspend ()->T): Flow<R> = channelFlow {
    val sendLoadingJob = launch {
        delay(cutoffDelay)
        send(loadState)
    }
    val value = fetchAction()
    sendLoadingJob.cancelAndJoin()
    send(value)
}
```

Usage:

```
lazyFlowOfWithLoadStateIfDelayed(1000L, Status.Loading) { Status.Data(repository.fetchData()) }
  .collect {
     when (it) {
       is Status.Loading -> // show loading indicator in case no data after X milliseconds
       is Status.Data -> // We have received the data.
     } 
  }
```

---

Edit: simpler way to build the above using `debounce`, based on Vivek Gupta's comments and answer. This works because `debounce` is optimized to pass through the last value of a finite flow immediately.

```
fun <R, T: R, L: R> lazyFlowOfWithLoadStateIfDelayed(cutoffDelay: Long, loadState: L, fetchAction: suspend ()->T): Flow<R> = flow {
    emit(loadState)
    emit(fetchAction())
}.debounce(cutoffDelay)
```

---

If `fetchData()` is a flow, for example a flow that infinitely monitors a database, you could build a flow operator that shows a load state only if the first item is slow:

```
fun <R, T: R, L: R> Flow<T>.emitLoadStateIfDelayed(cutoffDelay: Long, loadState: L): Flow<R> = channelFlow {
    val sendLoadingJob = launch {
        delay(cutoffDelay)
        send(loadState)
    }
    collect {
        sendLoadingJob.cancelAndJoin()
        send(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! These solutions make complete sense to me. I have completely missed channelFlow which I think is why I couldn't come up with a solution. I need to read up on it. Cheers!

Comment: I don't see why you need `channelFlow`. The `send`s you write have a clear happens-before relationship.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung What alternative are you suggesting? We don't know if the fetched value comes before or after the sent loading state.

Comment: The use of a channel makes concurrent emissions safe. But in your code the `send`s aren't concurrent, so I thought they can be replaced with simple `flow` and `emit`. But I tested that and you are right, calling `emit` from another coroutine is prohibited.

Comment: Yes, the FlowCollector of a regular `flow` builder is not thread-safe so it prohibits emission from other coroutines. To make the delay concurrent, we need another coroutine, so `channelFlow` becomes necessary.

Comment: FWIW, for the first case (the one with `suspend fun`), it can be done with `select`, `onAwait`, and `onTimeout` without using `channelFlow`.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung I want to work on `Flow<T>`. Would `select` and the rest also work with Flow?

Comment: I suggested `select` because I want to avoid using a channel. But as you can see in the [implementation of debounce](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/d653ab9b021716959df9f5b694cb5e92c1834840/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/operators/Delay.kt#L209), to concurrently wait for a timeout and elements in a `Flow`, it would need a channel anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a sealed class

```
 sealed class Status<out T> {
    object Loading : Status<Nothing>()
    data class Data<T>(val data: T) : Status<T>()
}
```

And your fetchData() is

```
suspend fun <T> fetchData(): T {
        delay(Random.nextLong(1000, 5000)) // simulate network delay
    return "data" as T
}
```

And Repository method which is emitting flow

```
fun <T> getData(): Flow<Status<T>> = flow {
    emit(Status.Loading)
    val data = fetchData<T>()
    emit(Status.Data(data))
}
```

you can create a method with timeout this using debounce. It will not delay the successful response.
getDataWithLoadingDelay will only delay the initial emission of a data value from the getData flow until the debounce time has elapsed. Once a data value has been emitted by the getData flow, it will be immediately emitted as a Status.Data value by the getDataWithLoadingDelay flow without any further delay.

```
fun <T> getDataWithLoadingDelay(delayMs: Long): Flow<Status<T>> = getData<T>()
    .debounce(delayMs)
    .map { status ->
        if (status is Status.Data) {
            status
        } else {
            Status.Loading
        }
    }
```

If no value is emitted during the debounce period, it emits a Status.Loading value to indicate that the data is still being fetched.

Comment: Oh right, because debounce is smart enough to emit the last value immediately if the source if finite and reaches the end. That is probably a cleaner way to build the first version in my answer.